# How do I load an ArrayList that I can acces and manipulate from other classes without loading them more than once?

Tags: java, list, csv, memory, arraylist

Lets say I have a class called Product which contains a counstructor like this

```
public Product(String name, double price, int barcode){
        this.name = name;
        this.barcode = barcode;
        this.price = price;
    }
```

I then have another class ImportData which have a method that load a lot of products into a List that returns a productList.

I now want to acces this list from different classes without have to load the data into the csv-file once again.
So instead of this:

```
ImportFruitAndVegatables iFV = new ImportFruitAndVegatables();
List<Product> products = iFV.fillListWithProducts();
```

I want something like this

```
mainController.products
```

Because my mainController already runs the method. Like this

```
List <Product> productList = importFruitAndVegatables.fillListWithProducts();
```

So my question is: Are there any way you only need to run this method once and dont need to run it again? Thank you!

Comment: Some things are not very clear to me. What's `mainController`? Can you give a bit more code so that we can get more context? In general, you can do this with lazy initialization: you load your list once and store it in memory then for all subsequent calls, you check if your list has been loaded already and if so, you return the list you have in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share a reference to an object in at least these ways:

- [Global variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable). In Java that is a static variable defined on a class. Mark as `final` if the object reference should be assigned only once during your app’s execution.
- [Singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). In Java, that is best done as an enum defining a single object named something like `INSTANCE`.
- Public instance variable. If `List <Product> productList` is a member field on your instance of `mainController`, then marking that field as `public` allows any other code to call `mainController.productList`.
- Pass the list as an argument to a method. For example, defining a method such as `public SalesReport produceSalesReport( List <Product> productList ) {…}`.
- A method that returns the object reference. This offers the opportunity for [lazy-loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) when the desired object is not instantiated until the first call to this method.

You do not provide enough detail to make a recommendation. Generally best to use a method that returns a list.

Tip: Generally best to provide either a copy of the list or a non-modifiable list so the calling programmer cannot disturb the original list. See `List.copyOf`.